COEP with images from Storyblok using Nuxt Security
I am trying to set Nuxt Security for my Nuxt 3 app. I add those lines into nuxt.config:
security: {
    headers: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'https://a.storyblok.com'],
      },
    },
  }

but I still have problems to load images from Storyblok with NuxtImg component.
I have this error:

GET https://a.storyblok.com/f/....... net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200 (OK)

I tried to add crossorigin="anonymous" into NuxtImg.
